# EF Code First foreign key with multiple keys

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have an event table that can have multiple event dates for it. I've done some research into this error, but it looks like I have everything set up correctly, however I'm new to the code first approach, and I think my confusion comes in with overriding the OnModelCreating

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Event_EventDates_Source_Event_EventDates_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.



[Table("EventDates")]
public class EventDate
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int EventDateId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime EventDateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventEnd { get; set; }
    public string TicketPurchaseUrl { get; set; }
}

[Table("Events")]
public class Event
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    ...
    public int EventDateId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDateStart { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EventDateId, EventDateStart")]
    public virtual ICollection<EventDate> EventDates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is a bit weird for the business logic you describe. If an `Event` can have many `EventDates` you should not have a foreign key in `Event` that refers to `EventDate`, but the other way around: A foreign key in `EventDate` that refers to `Event` and possibly also a navigation property `Event` in `EventDate`:

```
[Table("EventDates")]
public class EventDate
{
    public int EventDateId { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventEnd { get; set; }
    public string TicketPurchaseUrl { get; set; }
}

[Table("Events")]
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventDate> EventDates { get; set; }
}
```

By convention `EventDate.EventDateId` and `Event.EventId` will be the keys and they will be autogenerated. I suggest that you save yourself the trouble of having a `DateTime` as part of a composite key in `EventDate`. If you do not really need such a composite key keep it simple with just an `int` identity as key.